# Differences and thresholdis of ImageCollection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, data-collection

I have the following code (very basic as I am new user), and I want to create an `NDVI difference` collection by subtracting every NDVI image from my initial collection, with its previous one (something like NDVI2-NDVI1,NDVI3-NDVI2,...). 
After that, I want to do some thresholding and assign specific values, but I do not know how to do this.

My attempt:

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD43A4")
 .filterBounds(geometry)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(geometry)})
      .filterDate('2005-07-01','2005-08-31');
   var NDVIbands = imageCollection.select("Nadir_Reflectance_Band2","Nadir_Reflectance_Band1","BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_Band1","BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_Band2");
   var geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-53.90538056149785, -3.6610951156347706],
          [-53.860061957982225, -3.959810400282152],
          [-53.362930610325975, -3.8529425805852524],
          [-53.42198212399785, -3.5706383493989544]]]);

var masks = function(image){
  var mask1 = image.select("BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_Band1").eq(0);
  var mask2 = image.select("BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_Band2").eq(0);
  return image.updateMask(mask1).updateMask(mask2);
};

var filtered = NDVIbands.map(masks);

var myNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['Nadir_Reflectance_Band2', 'Nadir_Reflectance_Band1']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var NDVI = filtered.map(myNDVI);

//From this point, I need your help because I am not familiar with this.

//I do not know how to set the slices in order to subtract every NDVI from its previous
//(like NDVI2-NDVI1,NDVI3-NDVI2,...).Based on what I want, my NDVIdif collection must have
//one element less than the initial NDVI collection.

var NDVIdif = NDVI.slice(,).subtract(NDVI.slice(,))


//And here, I want to create classes based on value-limits but again, I do not know how to do this.

var reclass = function(img) {
  var mclass = img.remap([-0.250 - -0.103,-0.105 - 0.201],[  1,   2],   null, 'reclass dNDVI');    
  return mclass;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you first question, it is possibly bet practice to first make a list of a certain property in every image. You can then get every current and previous image based on the value in the list:

```
// First make a list of a useful numerical property of the image collection 
// and make sure they are ordered by time
var NDVI = filtered.map(myNDVI).sort('system:time_start');
var dateList = ee.List(NDVI.aggregate_array('system:time_start')).slice(1); // remove the first date


// Now map over that list, so we now the index of each image (and thus it's previous)
var NDVIdiff = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(dateList.map(function(date){

  // get the image corresponding to the date
  var currentImage = NDVI.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:time_start', date)).first();

  // Now we have to get the 'previous' image in the collection
  var indexCurrent = dateList.indexOf(date);
  var indexPrevious = indexCurrent.subtract(1);
  var datePrevious = dateList.get(indexPrevious);
  var previousImage = NDVI.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:time_start', datePrevious)).first();

  // Subtract the current image from the previous
  var diffImage = currentImage.subtract(previousImage).select(['NDVI'], ['NDVIdiff']);

  // return the image
  return currentImage.addBands(diffImage)
            .set('system:index_previous', previousImage.get('system:index'));
}));
```

For the second question, I guess you want the NDVI values in a certain range to be labelled to an integer. An option to do that  I show below:

```
// list of numbers to reclass:
var reclassList = [-0.250, -0.103, 0.201, 0.4, 0.6];

var reclass = function(image) {
  // Map over the list
  var reclass = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(ee.List(reclassList).sort().map(function(value){
    // every value gt a certain number in the reclass List will be 1. 
    // The returned image will ths be 0 for values lower than the lowest value, and a multiple of ones for every next number
    return image.select('NDVI').gt(ee.Number(value)); // I guess you want to this for the NDVI band?
  }))
  // make a summed image and reproject to the origonal projection of the images
  .reduce('sum').rename('reclassNDVI')
  // eventually reproject into the origonal image projection
  .reproject(image.projection(),null, image.projection().nominalScale()); 

  return image.addBands(reclass);
};

// Run the function and print
var reclassCollection = NDVI.map(reclass);
```

[Link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b384479f2f889b94ca5b474384ba7525)

Comment: Hello @Kuik and thank you very much for your answer and very useful comments! I do have a few questions regarding the reclass. Why you only used numbers and not limits(you used 3 numbers from my above mentioned limits and then 2 other numbers 0.4 and 0.6)? My last question, why you make a sum image and reproject? Isn't the map over a collection function works for this kind of things? (e.g. to map the reclass function over the difference ndvi collection).

Comment: I show you a way to reclassify values in a range of NDVI to integers. There are, off course, multiple other ways. You could apply a similar approach with different limit values on the difference image, if desired. I reproject because when you make a composite (summed in this case), the image looses it's original projection. As stated, re-projecting is not necessary.

Comment: Very clear, thank you very much!